# Continue execution of previous session log on exception

Tags: python, ipython, interactive, ipython-magic

I'm trying to build a workflow for me to start and resume iPython sessions when debugging issues on a remote machine. I want to log everything I type in, replay it, and have execution continue on errors.

**With exception**: I tried to access x before it was defined. Replaying session.log paused on this error, so the value for x was never set even though it was assigned on the next line.

[image: iPython with exception]

**Without exception**: I only tried to access x after it was assigned, so there were no errors.

[image]

**Goal**: Have my session.log file potentially contain errors, but still continue execution on the next line.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want isn’t so much resumable sessions as rather the ability for a remote session to continue running when you log out, is that correct? In this case I recommend you use [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki), which is the specific tool for that job, instead of trying to record and replay. iPython sessions.

Comment: Sometimes I write custom code for debugging and need to reboot the a stateful machine to continue. A resumable iPython session is indeed what I'm looking for.